# Error: Champ 'product_name' inconnu dans field list

Tags: php, mysql, wampserver

I am trying to store form data in a database using WampServer.

When I click on the submit button it shows me this error:

```
"Error: Champ 'product_name' inconnu dans field list".
```

I am using the same work for another form. That form is working but i dont know what is wrong with this one, Please help me out

My form code is :

```
<form action="saddproduct.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="myForm" id="myForm" 
 method="post"> 
    <table width="90%" border="1" cellpadding="6">
        <tr>
            <td width="20%">Product Name</td>
            <td width="80%"> 
                <label> 
                <input name="product_name" type="text" id="product_name" size="60" /> 
            </label>    
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width="20%">Product Code</td>
            <td width="80%"> 
                <label> 
                    <input name="product_code" type="text" id="product_code" size="60" /> 
                </label>    
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width="20%">Product Availability</td>
            <td width="80%"> 
            <label>
                <select name="availability" id="availability">
                    <option value=""></option>
                    <option value="in"> In Stock </option>
                    <option value="out"> Out Of Stock </option>
                    </select>
                </label>    
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width="20%">Product Price</td>
            <td width="80%">
            <label>
                Rs.
                <input name="price" type="text" id="price" size="12"  />
            </label>    
            </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
             <td align="right">Category</td>
            <td>
        <label>
                <select name="category" id="category">
                    <option value=""></option>
                    <option value="living"> Living Rooms </option>
                    <option value="bed"> Bed Rooms </option>
                    <option value="dining"> Dining Rooms </option>
                    </select>
                </label>    
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="right">Sub category</td>
            <td>
                <label>
                    <select name="subcategory" id="subcategory">
                        <option value=""></option>
                        <option value="lsofa"> Lining Sofa </option>
                        <option value="lchair"> Living Chair </option>
                        <option value="ltable"> Living Table </option>
                        <option value="bking"> King Beds </option>
                        <option value="bqueen"> Queen Beds </option>
                        <option value="dtable"> Dining Tables </option>
                        <option value="dchairs"> Dining Chairs </option>
                        <option value="hsale"> Sale Item For Home Page </option>
                        <option value="psale"> Sale Item For Sale Page </option>
                    </select>
                </label>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width="20%">Product Detail</td>
            <td width="80%">
            <label>
                <textarea name="details" id="details" cols="64" rows="5"> </textarea>
            </label>    
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;  </td>
            <td width="80%"> 
                <label> 
                    <input type="submit" name="button" id="button" class="button" value="Add This  
         Product Now"  />
                </label>    
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width="20%">&nbsp;</td>
            <td width="80%">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
   </table>
</form>
```

And my processing PHP page is saddproduct.php which look like :

```
<?php
    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","03005225400","furniture");
    // Check connection
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }


    // escape variables for security
    $product_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['product_name']);
    $product_code = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['product_code']);
    $availability = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['availability']);

    $price = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['price']);
    $category = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['category']);
    $subcategory = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['subcategory']);

    $details = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['details']);


    $sql="INSERT INTO employee 
              (product_name , product_code, availability, price, 
               category, subcategory, details, date_added) 
          VALUES('$product_name','$product_code', '$availability',     
                '$price','$category','$subcategory','$details',now())" 
          or die (mysql_error());

    if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql)) {
      die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
    }

    mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: no no no. remove that `or die()` ... you are just setting a string there.

Comment: Anyway, I think the error message is clear, though French. You don't have a field called `product_name` in that table.

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);

 mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);`

Comment: I am already using die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));

Comment: @user3694543 that is correct, just remove the other die: `or die(mysql_error())`

Comment: i have product_name field in the table @nl-x

Comment: @user3694543 No you don't. Not in that table, in that database, on that host. That is what the error message is telling you.

Comment: I ahve removed or die(mysql_error()) but still same error :( @nl-x

Comment: @user3694543 It was just a side note. I didn't expect it to fix anything.

Comment: By adding erroe reporting its shows me this " Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'mysqli_sql_exception' with message 'Champ 'product_name' inconnu dans field list' " @Fred-ii-

Comment: @user3694543 As already stated, you most likely don't have a column called `product_name`. Yet, I see a space here `product_name ,` try removing it to be `product_name,` I have a hunch about that. Also for `category ,`

Comment: @user3694543 Just double, triple, quadruple, pentuple and even hextuple-check that you are on the correct host/database/table and the column is spelled correctly

Comment: @user3694543 Make sure your column isn't `product name` you might have forgotten to name it with an underscore. Or, you may have used an hyphen.

Comment: i removed that space but still no improvement @Fred-ii-

Comment: CREATE TABLE products ( 
                id int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment, 
                product_name varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    product_code varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    availability varchar(255) NOT NULL, 
                price varchar(255) NOT NULL, 
    details text NOT NULL,
    category varchar(16) NOT NULL,
    subcategory varchar(16) NOT NULL,
    date_added date NOT NULL,
                PRIMARY KEY (id), 
                UNIQUE KEY product_name (product_name) 
                )";

Comment: this is my table script

Comment: That is table `products`, your query is table `employee`

Comment: Do `$sql="INSERT INTO products` then. That's the issue.

Answer (score 4):

I am sure that if you verify your table structure you wont find any column named **product_name**, at least not with the exact case.

Try verifying your column names, and if you still dont have a clue, try removing column names and sticking to the order of your table structure while putting *NULL* in fields with default content like auto increment and timestamps.

Comment: case shouldn't matter

Comment: @nl-x you're right, I made a confusion between mysql and pgsql

Answer (score 0):

Simple typo. Table `employee` should be `products`

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes this(Error: Champ 'Yes' inconnu dans field list) type error occurs due to using (`) this single quotes rather than using (') this quotes in INSERT query.